# What "->" means in Java

Tags: java

I'm the beginner in Java simple things are new to me. Besides my level google doesn't want to search such keywords like "->" :)

I found it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm). So I think this code is correct.

Please help me to understand what does this expression mean?

```
firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
        (CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) -> {
            ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
```

Comment: It's a lambda expression. Here is a tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a lambda expression - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html.

It is new in java 8.

When an interface has only one method and is annotated with @FunctionalInterface then it is a functional interface.  This allows you to use the "->" syntax to bypass a lot of verbose boilerplate code.

You can replace

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
});
```

with

```
btn.setOnAction(
  event -> System.out.println("Hello World!")
);
```